# Can I prevent argparse from exiting if the user specifies '-h'?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm writing a program that loads a bunch of data and then allows to user to query it for different reports. Since I don't want to load the data again and again, I've written an interactive portion for it.

I want the commands in this interactive portion to be parsed via argparse, but argparse always exits if someone specifies `-h` or `--help`. I don't want it to do that - I just want to print the help message and continue looping. Can I tell argparse not to exit if -h is provided?

Answer (score 3):

You could define your own `help` argument.  There's a parameter in the `ArgumentParser` definition that turns off the automatic help.

If your own `help` is a 'store_true', then after parsing you could check that, and do a `parse.print_help()` command.  (or `format_help` if you just want the string).  Or it could be a custom class.

One thing you have to decide is whether, with the `help` you want it to ignore all the other arguments (as the default help does), or whether this custom help is just one of many.

But catching the `SystemExit` is a valid approach.

The default `help` is handled by:

```
class _HelpAction(Action):

    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest=SUPPRESS,
                 default=SUPPRESS,
                 help=None):
        super(_HelpAction, self).__init__(
            option_strings=option_strings,
            dest=dest,
            default=default,
            nargs=0,
            help=help)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit()
```

This is distinctive in that it takes no args (like a 'store_true'), does `print_help` and does a `exit`.

`parser.exit` can also be modified; it is briefly described in the docs.  It's the one that does the `sys.exit()` call.  It's also called after parsing errors.  If you are doing your own parsing loop you might want to change that.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out. In my python3 interpreter I can do something like this.

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
try:
    args = p.parse_args(['-h'])
except SystemExit:
    print('hi')
```

And then I see 'hi' printed.